# Can code from a garbage-collected language generate a Unikernel?

Tags: garbage-collection, unikernel

The system development world is excited about Unikernels lately. In short, Unikernels are applications that are compiled to a self-contained, bootable operating system rather than a process in an existing operating system.

**Is there any theoretical problem or practical caveat for compiling a Unikernel from a garbage-collected language like Google's Go?**

Answer (score 6):

There is no theoretical problem or practical caveat for compiling a unikernel from a garbage-collected language. In fact, one of the first unikernel projects, [MirageOS](https://mirage.io/), is a framework for developing unikernels in [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/), a functional programming language with a garbage collector. Language-specific unikernel frameworks for Haskell, [HaLVM](http://galois.com/project/halvm/), and Erlang/OTP, [LING](http://erlangonxen.org/), also exist and have growing user communities. There are even golang-based unikernel projects like [Clive](http://lsub.org/ls/clive.html).

Browse [the unikernel.org projects list](http://unikernel.org/projects/) for a more comprehensive and up-to-date list of the exploding unikernel project space.